# add sobject to a list that is inside a list javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, salesforce

I have a list called joinList that contains an sobject and a list of sobject. it look like this

```
0:
   employeeRole:
      Employee__c:"a1n2C0000002SGqQAM"
      Id:"a1m2C000000cJaxQAE"
      Name:"Smith"
   employeeBlock:
        0:
            Id:"a1u2C00000011FQQAY"
            Name:"Week 2"
            Week_Number__c:2
            Total_Hours__c:4
        1:
            Id:"a1u2C00000011FQQAY"
            Name:"Week 5"
            Week_Number__c:5
            Total_Hours__c:6
1:{employeeRole: Array(0), employeeBlock: {…}}
```

I have integer field that get me the number of weeks called numberOfWeeksInput,
Goal is if the number of the week is 5. 
I want to check if there is a employeeBlock existing for the each week if its not create one for each week.

the result will be 
I have already week 2 and 5 I want to create ones for week 1,3, and 4.

**Update Answer**
I have a code looks like this im asking if there is another way to simplify it without using jquery

```
    var numberOfWeekList =[];
       for(var t = 0; t < numberOfWeeksInput;t++){
            numberOfWeekList.push((t+1));
        }
if( numberOfWeeksInput != null && numberOfWeeksInput != 0){
   for(var i = 0; i < joinList.length;i++){
        var empolyeeBlock = joinList[i].empolyeeBlock ;
        var existWeeks= [];
        if(empolyeeBlock !== null && empolyeeBlock.length !== 0){
         for(var t = 0; t < empolyeeBlock.length;t++){                        
             existWeeks.push(empolyeeBlock[t].Week_Number__c);
             }
         }
         var numberOfWeekUnassighned = numberOfWeekList.filter( ( el ) => !existWeeks.includes( el ) );
        if(numberOfWeekUnassighned !== null && numberOfWeekUnassighned.length !==0 && numberOfWeekUnassighned.length !== numberOfWeeksInput){
        for(var k = 0; k < numberOfWeekUnassighned.length;k++){
                            employeeBlock.push({
                                'sobjectType': 'EmployeeBlock__c',
                                'Name': 'Week '+(numberOfWeekUnassighned[k]),
                                'Week_Number__c':(numberOfWeekUnassighned[k]),
                                'Total_Hours__c':null
                            })
                        }
                    roleEstimateBlock.sort((a , b) => a.Week_Number__c - b.Week_Number__c);
                    }else if( employeeBlock.length <= numberOfWeeksInput){
                        for(var j = 0; j < numberOfWeeksInput;j++){
                            employeeBlock.push({
                                'sobjectType': 'EmployeeBlock__c',
                                'Name': 'Week '+(j+1),
                                'Week_Number__c':(j+1),
                                'Total_Hours__c':null
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }  
            }
```

Comment: If would be nice if the data you posted was valid javascript so that if anyone wants to help you they need to to format your code to make it runnable. Consider editing it so arrays are in `[]` and objects are in `{}`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer they problem the data is coming in huge just give me a little time i will edit my question with snippet of the data. it looks like this below comment

Comment: @MarkMeyer  [{employeeBlock: Array(5), employeeRole: {…}},{employeeBlock: Array(5), employeeRole: {…}},]

Comment: The code is not doing its job because the length of an array is the index of the last entry plus one, not the number of entries. Please look up sparse arrays if this is unclear. Try iterating through the array from 0 to the number of weeks less one and check for undefined entries that need to be created.

Comment: @traktor53  I got solution for the problem I update the question with solution, is there is a a way to simplify the solution

Comment: @MarkMeyer  I got solution for the problem I update the question with solution, is there is a a way to simplify the solution